# How to simulate "enter key press" in Process working in background?

Tags: c#, process

In my executable `Process` instance I have a couple of `Console.ReadLine` lines. How to pass `Enter key press` (simulate enter key press by user) in `Process.InputStream` class? How `enter` key should look in input string?

```
// in string input I want to have information, that "user" pressed enter key  
this.Process.StandardInput.Write(input);
```

My Process work on background and I have set the

```
this.Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

flag.

**EDIT:**

In my `exe` file exist code like that:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       array[i] = Console.ReadLine();
   }
```

And i want simulate enter key press on `input string` in my `Process.StandardInput.Write`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WriteLine()`.

```
this.Process.StandardInput.WriteLine();
```

Or you can write the newline sequence manually.

```
this.Process.StandardInput.Write(this.Process.StandardInput.NewLine);
```

Either way set `AutoFlush` to true

```
this.Process.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
```

or flush manually after you have written.

```
this.Process.StandardInput.Flush();
```

If you want to send more lines at once just send more newlines at once, preceded by any text you want.

```
this.Process.StandardInput.Write(  "a" + this.Process.StandardInput.NewLine
                                 + "b" + this.Process.StandardInput.NewLine);
```

Comment: Could you tell me, how it will work? Because when i have "happy path" scenerio with one input and one output from precompiled `.exe` file i just use one `StandardInput.Write` and then `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` and it works ok. How your code will be related to multiline `Console.Writelines`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question... If you want to write more lines repeat that sequence or just write them all at once and flush after you're done. It may even flush automatically but I wouldn't bet on that but you may try of course.

Comment: I edited my question with expected scenerio. Can i do triple `Console.ReadLine` from `.exe` file in one `StandardInput`?

Comment: @michasaucer: Still not sure what the problem is. You want to know how to concatenate strings? Then see my edit.